# rails: heroku run console giving error "bash: console: command not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Using the cedar-14 stack on Heroku. Just noticed that I can no longer run `heroku run console` because I get the error:

> bash: console: command not found

I can still get to the console by calling:

```
heroku run bundle exec rails console
```

But I'm wondering what might have caused this change. I only noticed the issue after several days of commits so I can pinpoint the issue.

Comment: what happens when you try `heroku run rails console`?

Comment: it throws bash: rails: command not found

Answer (score 5):

You need to use

> heroku run rails console

The Basics for Heroku are explained under [Heroku Devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4).

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
heroku run /app/bin/rails console
```

I happened to see this problem for a preview apps. For regular apps `heroku console` works.

Comment: I tried this, but it said `bash: /app/bin/rails: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try @dthal's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem but I have resolved it by removing `heroku/metrics` build pack.
I have followed the configuration given for `Ruby Language Metrics` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/language-runtime-metrics-ruby and then tried to run the command `heroku run console` and it was triggering `command not found error` then I have reverted my changes and it started working.

Hope this will be helpful!